# When Trying to access the excel file in post request, getting this error "MultiValueDictKeyError(key)"

Tags: python, django, excel, django-rest-framework, openpyxl

**CODE**

```
import openpyxl

class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    API user to import hospital's adimission data in bulk, using xls file
    '''
    
    # getting the excel file
    # try:
    #     excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
    # except:
    #     return Response({'err_msg': 'bad request'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
    
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
    # getting a particular sheet by name out of many sheets
    worksheet = wb['Sheet1']
    # excel_data = []
    print(worksheet)
```

**Error**

File "G:\office\medicover\medicover_bloodbank_django\file_app\views.py", line 27, in post
excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
File "G:\office\medicover\medicover_bloodbank_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in **getitem**
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'excel_file'
[07/Jul/2022 06:50:29] "POST /file/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 103875

Comment: How are you uploading the file to your view? What do you get if you print out `request.data`?

Comment: i am uploading through postman and getting while doing request.data...   <QueryDict: {'remark': ['addimission data 3'], 'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: excel_file.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>]}>

Comment: `request.FILES` does not contain an item named `excel_file`.  We can't help any further, because you haven't shown us the details of how the file is uploaded.

Comment: I am uploading a file "excel_file.xlsx" through postman

Comment: In the view, print the contents of `request.FILES`

Comment: <MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: excel_file.xls (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>

Comment: Then that's the answer.  You should be using `file`, not `excel_file`.

Answer (score 1):

The error was a result of this line of code:-
excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

Because I was passing "excel_file". However, this should be a "file" like this:-
excel_file = request.FILES["file"]

instead of providing a "key", I was providing the value "excel_file".

So, by just changing "excel_file" to "file" I got the result.